# Bitcoin database needs to rebuild every time after defrag or reboot

Tags: blockchain, database

I'm running Windows 10 technical preview 10049 and I'm running bitcoin-qt from my data hard drive with 1.17TB available disk space. It is a striped volume and due to much data writing and deleting it needs to be defragmented from time to time. Every time I have done this and I start Bitcoin-QT again it gives an error that the database needs to be rebuild what takes ages.

Comment: That's very odd. Unless your defragmentation program is changing the data it operates on, it shouldn't cause Bitcoin to need to reindex.

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown Bitcoin-QT cleanly and no reindexing is needed.

The reindexing of bitcoind database is only needed if the application did not have time to properly shut itself down and write all information in its memory to disk.

Comment: It probably the shutdown procedure of Windows 10. With Windows 7 I also ran defraggler with an automated shutdown when finished and never had a problem. It now forces to shutdown every program but it is to fast to let bitcoin shutdown correct what causes the problem. In short, no automated shutdown after defrag is done or close bitcoin before leaving computer.

Comment: @JoostdeBruijne make this an answer!